# Find Specific Cell in Pandas Dataframe Then Fill new column with it

Tags: python, pandas, cell

I am new to python and have a pretty basic question.
I am trying to reformat an excel sheet, the excel sheet has a specific cell with a value in it. I need to take this value and fill in a new column with it.

I have my data in Pandas and have found the specific cells location in the dataframe.

`SpecificCell = df.iloc[0:1,11:12]`

(im not sure this was the best way to do that though)

I have also created a new column in my dataframe and filled it with NAN.

`DataFrame1['SpecificCellColumn'] = np.nan`

Now I need to fill in the 'SpecifcCellColumn' with the value in SpecificCell.
This is where I get stuck. I tried the following but it of course did not work.

```
DataFrame1.fillna(SpecificCell, inplace=True)
```

Any help is appreciated. How do I find a specific cell in a dataframes value then fill a new column with it.

Comment: does `DataFrame1.fillna(SpecificCell.values[0], inplace=True)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create an empty column and then fill it?

```
specific_cell = df.iloc[0,11]
df['SpecificCell'] = specific_cell
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didnt fully understand the df.iloc which was causing me issues